# How to stack or order the flash object element in html

Tags: html, css, flash, object

I am trying to make the display priority of the flash object as low as my other div(specially drop-down div), but its not working

I have tried 2 things :

1.Changing the z-index

```
<div id="dropdown" style="position:relative; z-index:4"></div>
<object id="flash_object" style="position:relative; z-index:0;"></object>
```

2.Adding the param wmode

```
    <object id="flash_object" style="position:relative; z-index:0;">
    <param name="WMODE" value="TRANSPARENT">
    </object>
```

None of the above are working .. suggest me what to do now :( .. thanx

Answer (score 0):

This?

Do you want that the dropdown appear over the object flash right? I've removed the object and used div.
If you have the web src from the object, I can test.

```
<div id="flash_object"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VR4G3/1/

Answer (score 0):

finally, with many permutation and combinations of z-index and positions, i got it with 2 simple lines ...

Set position:relative for the div in which your flash resides and then add param wmode with value of transparent or opaque

there was no need of using z-index  ..

Thanx to people, who answered my question :)